# Does the usage of PC muscle to achieve multiple orgasm in males cancels or transfers the ejacuation to the bludder?

Tags: sex, male, ejaculation, orgasm-climax

There is a concept about dry/multiple male orgasm. Most common idea is what by practicing clenching of ones pubococcygeus (PC) muscle just before a point when the process of ejacuation begins, a male can achieve orgasm without ejacuating or rest/refactory period.
Question is: out of these options (or other which are not listed here) which is the true one?
1. Clenching PC muscle cancels the process of ejacuation and  the inflow of rest/refactory chemicals, but not the orgasm.
2. The ejacuation still continues to the next available "outlet", i.e. the bludder?

Comment: @paparazzo, What do you mean?